# How to make infinitive clauses in German such as

Tags: english-to-german, single-word-request, sentence-structure, infinitive

How can I make a sentence like this:

> Not to love each other in a relationship is not endurable for any of us most of the time.

Or

> It's not so easy for me to think about my parents or anything else.

These are only samples. I hope I could have told what I meant.

Comment: Please edit your post to state your question more clearly. The title is not supposed to be a part of the question but only a short summary of the while post.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a usefull website for you which explains infinitive clauses in english and german pretty well:
http://www.dartmouth.edu/~deutsch/Grammatik/WordOrder/Infinitives.html

Comment: Please avoid link only answers.